# Warning Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: magento2, indexing, mysql-indexes

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and getting 5 warning logs in `system.log` file while I run the command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size.
```

So far I have done the below steps

1.

```
Increased the value of variable innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1G inside
        /etc/my.cnf and restarted MySQL.
```

2. `I have added the code in my app/etc/env.php file`

> ```
> 'indexer' => [
>         'batch_size' => [
>             'cataloginventory_stock' => [
>                 'simple' => 200
>             ],
>             'catalog_category_product' => 666,
>             'catalogsearch_fulltext' => [
>                 'partial_reindex' => 100,
>                 'mysql_get' => 500,
>                 'elastic_save' => 500
>             ],
>             'catalog_product_price' => [
>                 'simple' => 200,
>                 'default' => 500,
>                 'configurable' => 666
>             ],
>             'catalogpermissions_category' => 999,
>             'inventory' => [
>                 'simple' => 210,
>                 'default' => 510,
>                 'configurable' => 616
>             ]
>         ]
>     ]
> ```

Now the number of logs decreased to 1

I have added the below code in my custom module /etc/adminhtml/di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">1000</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\BatchSizeCalculator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">500</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Still, there is one warning message log, how to resolve this?